# Rails form_tag needs refreshing

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Hi I have been stuck on the following issue for days, and I just dont know whats going wrong...

I have the following form_tag code in my partial view, which is displayed with a remote add to cart from a main view:

```
<tr>
  <% form_tag line_item, :method => :put do %>
    <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price" ><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
    <td>
      <%= text_field :line_item, :quantity, :size => 1, :value => line_item.quantity %>
      <%= submit_tag 'update' %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
  <td>
    <%= button_to 'Delete Line Item', line_item, :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

now when i click add to cart, the above is rendered in the id where I have the replace.html function targeted but...

i can't actually update the cart using the update button unless I refresh the page!! I have no idea what the matter is and its driving me mad!

Has anyone got any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: what does your controller look like? it should either respond by rendering some JS that does what you want, or return something that some JS on your page can act on to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think form_tag needs `:remote => true` also.